# Creating Template Links for Pagination in Generic CBV

Tags: django, django-views

I'm just starting with Django so I have a lot of questions. I've built a Mixin to create the paginator template links for "next page" and previous page in a GCBV (ListView):

```
class PageLinksMixin:
page_kwarg = 'page'

def _page_urls(self, page_number):
    return "?{pkw}={n}".format(pkw=self.page_kwarg, n=page_number)

def previous_page(self, page):
    if page.has_previous():
        return self._page_urls(page.previous_page_number())
    return None

def next_page(self, page):
    if page.has_next():
        return self._page_urls(page.next_page_number())
    return None

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    page = context.get('page_obj')
    if page is not None:
        context.update({'previous_page_url': self.previous_page(page),
                        'next_page_url': self.next_page(page)})
    return context
```

Everything seems to work. But I can simply not see where some of the inputs for functions were created. Especially "page", "page_number". 
With a CBV it would be necessary to declare:

```
page = paginator.page(page_number)
```

But in the GCBV this is apparently unnecessary which means the attribute is created somewhere and later inherited.
For the ListView there is a function **def paginate_queryset** but in there page is only declared in a local scope not a global scope. Can somebody explain this to me? I'm really confused and trying to figure this out for a while now.

This is the View:

```
class TagList(PageLinksMixin, ListView):
template_name = 'organizer/tag_list.html'
paginate_by = 5
model = Tag
```

Answer (score 1):

The Django generic `ListView` has a paginator object, which is added to the context through `self.get_context_data()`. Here's the Django source code:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    """
    Get the context for this view.
    """
    queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
    page_size = self.get_paginate_by(queryset)
    context_object_name = self.get_context_object_name(queryset)
    if page_size:
        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(queryset, page_size)
        context = {
            'paginator': paginator,
            'page_obj': page,
            'is_paginated': is_paginated,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    else:
        context = {
            'paginator': None,
            'page_obj': None,
            'is_paginated': False,
            'object_list': queryset
        }
    if context_object_name is not None:
        context[context_object_name] = queryset
    context.update(kwargs)
    return super(MultipleObjectMixin, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

In your mixin, you first call `super().get_context_data()`, which populates the context with the paginator and a page object, which you set to `page`:

```
page = context.get('page_obj')
```

Finally you call `self.previous_page(page)` to fetch the actual URL and add it to the context. Nothing magic.

You could also have fetched the page_number from the `kwargs` and the `page` from the `paginator` instance but since it's already done for you, the `page_obj` in the context is the easiest way.

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I've had some brain blockage with that, but you were able to help. Vielen Dank dafür ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Django Unleashed is a good book, but I personally don't use GCBVs that much because they obfuscate a lot. If you don't customise much they're fine, but if you do customise a lot it gets really hard to read the code's logic, especially if you're working on a project where other developers might need to step in later.